# Polish-language pop artists?

Tags: pop, language

I got my Irish-American sister a CD by Iarla Ó Lionáird awhile back. Now I want to get my Polish-American brother in law something similar -- namely, a modern CD or record in his heritage language.

**Could someone post some examples of people currently producing pop albums who sing in the Polish language?**

Answer (score 2):

I ended up just looking up some stuff by Czesław Niemen on YouTube. YouTube then suggested several other similar artists, after which things rolled along nicely.